flagged post as "no sources"
I answered this question a few days ago and it has since received quite a bit of criticism. Now its flagged as not having any sources when it clearly has 3. It had 2 before I added another one a moment ago but I mean its so basic psychology I don't really think it needed massive amounts of citations. What's up with that?
Name needed for psychological practice which uses objects that represent humans [dolls/pictures/etc.] during patient treatment

I added the notice to it because of the many comments underneath which question the correctness of the answer which still haven't been addressed/discussed fully. I figured the notice was important since the answer shows up as the accepted answer while the discussion in the comments indicate there might be severe problems with the answer.
I removed the notice since I agree 'no sources' is not the accurate description here. Unfortunately I can't add a custom one. The fact that the answer has currently negative votes will have to be enough indication it is problematic for now, along with the highly up voted comments explaining the issue.

The arguments against the answer were not valid though. Nit picking about the function of the doll. When anatomically correct dolls are one way for. psy. find out how a child has been abused. I even explained how they did it.

You were criticized for misrepresenting the sources you reference. Others agreed since that comment has 3 up votes, so 4 people agree your answer doesn't reflect your references. Update the answer to reflect the content of what you reference and it should be okay. In other words, read the comment, try to understand the critique, see whether you agree with it or not, if not argue against, if you do, update the post accordingly.

@caseyr547 I've removed the notice, see my updated description in the answer.

Thank you I appreciate it

I only just noticed that you edited your answer and addressed my criticism. I undid my downvote (which I explained in my comment), as it has become obsolete.

thanks :) i appreciate it
